# How to load custom config file in CodeIgniter's "core" folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to extend default CodeIgniter's class `CI_Lang` by creating a file `/core/MY_Lang.php`, and inside that file I need to load a custom configuration file:

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

    var $CI;

    // Default langs
    var $languages = array(
        'en' => 'english',
        'fr' => 'french'
    );

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        global $CFG;

        $this->CI  =& get_instance(); // NOT WORKING

        // Load custom config file from /config/languages.php
        $this->languages = $this->CI->config->item('languages');

    }

}
```

and `/config/languages.php` custom config file:

```
$config['languages'] = array(
    'en' => 'english',
    'fr' => 'french',
    'ru' => 'russian',
    'sk' => 'slovak'
);
```

Whenever I call for `get_instance` - I get an error telling me `Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in D:\wamp\www\ci2exp6\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233`

Please, could someone clarify what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: get_instance() was provided through CI_Controller. It's not a general method for all CI classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of a core library you need to call it as follows:

```
$CFG =& load_class('Config', 'core');
$CFG->load('languages', true);

$languages = $CFG->config['languages'];
$english   = $languages['en'];
//etc...
```

That should do the trick :)

Updated config file from comment:

```
$config['en'] = 'english';
$config['fr'] = 'french';
$config['ru'] = 'russian';
$config['sk'] = 'slovak';
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it would be a core-hack? If so, I would like to not touch the core files

Comment: It's the standard way to access core classes in codeigniter core libs.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I did it this way: `$CFG->load('languages');`. Could you modify your answer so I will accept it.

Comment: You also need to fix your config file: should be as follows...

$config['en'] = 'english';
$config['fr'] = 'french';